# Java: работа с MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, java, sql

Такой вопрос.
На сайте есть БД mySQL. Есть андроид-приложение.

Приложение должно проверять версию базы данных на сервере, после чего скачивать саму БД.
Простыми словами, в случае необходимости (версию БД на сайте больше скачанной) скачивать базу с сервера и уже использовать её оффлайн.

Как то реализовать? Есть ли уже готовые реализации?

Comment: Зачем скачивать базу, если вы не сможете её использовать на Android устройстве?

Comment: Т.е. я не смогу пользоваться скачанной БД? Как тогда быть? Если нужно держать БД на сервере и обновлять при надобности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> т.е. я не смогу пользоваться скачанной БД

Сомневаюсь, что вы сможете запустить MySQL на андроиде.

Пусть сервер отдает дамп базы в каком-нибудь промежуточном формате (xml, json, protobuf, csv, со сжатием, если объем велик). Локально вы ее развернете в какой-нибудь sqlite.

Разумеется, на сервере делать дамп и паковать в архив нужно по расписанию. А пользователю давать уже готовый файл с диска.

Comment: Автор поста не понимает разницы между СУБД и данными, которые хранятся в СУБД. Я так понимаю, что приложение должно скачивать данные, а не саму бд, всё же.